# How to Override Update Method in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a ticketing system that's linked to timesheets. Whenever someone updates a ticket, they have the option of submitting how much time has been spent on it, in a time_spent form object. Timesheets are polymorphically linked to many objects.

I want to create a trait, CreatesTimesheets, then apply that to relevant models so that:

- Each of those models gets a timesheets() function.
- It overrides the update() method of each model that it's a trait of, to check whether any time was submitted in time_spent.

It's the second bit that isn't working. My code is as below, and when I update the model (which works fine), this code doesn't fire at all, even testing it with a simple dd().

How do I fix this?

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\Models\HR\Timesheet;
use Auth;

trait CreatesTimesheets
{
    public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = [])
    {
        dd('test');
        if ($request->time_spent) 
        {
            $timesheet = new Timesheet;
            $timesheet->time_logged_in_mins = $request->time_spent;
            $timesheet->appointment_id      = Auth::user()->appointedJobIDToUse();
            $this->timesheets()->save($timesheet);
        }

        parent::update($attributes, $options);
    }

    public function timesheets()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\HR\Timesheet', 'timesheetable');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use observers for that purpose and not overriding this method.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers
You can create an static method in your trait to register the update event in the models ::boot() method

Comment: please show you Model also. have you include this trat?